# django field/widget for multiple values

Tags: django, django-forms

I seriously can't figure out how to manage to do this.

I would like to use django forms to validate the following (unknown number of `aname`):

```
<input type="hidden" name="aname" value="someJSONdump1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="aname" value="someJSONdump2"/>
<input type="hidden" name="aname" value="someJSONdump3"/>
<input type="hidden" name="aname" value="someJSONdump4"/>
```

and on the django side, I'm calling:

```
form = myforms.MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
if (form.is_valid()):
    # do something
else:
    # redisplay the form
```

How do I define `MyForm` to allow me to validate each `aname` and also, when in error, the widget to redisplay the above `<input>s`?

I can't figure out how to use the [MultiValueField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#multivaluefield) or even if it's the right thing to use. It seems to be a solution when you know how many fields you have?

Using `clean_aname()` in the form is no help as `self.cleaned_data.get('aname')` is only the last value.

Without the form, I would use something like `request.POST.getlist('aname')`, but I would like to avoid this if I can do it with `django.forms`.

Thanks for your help.

---

*****EDIT*****

I've left aside that I was defining more fields from a ModelForm. I think this might have some effects with formset. Here is where I am at... Is this solution considered to be "Django forms" compatible?

```
class MyField(forms.Field):
    widget = MyWidget

    def to_python(self, value):
        if (isinstance(value, basestring)):
            value = [value]
        return [json.loads(v) for v in value]

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel

    aname = MyField()

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(MyForm, self).clean()
        cleaned_data['aname'] = self.fields['aname'].clean(self.data.getlist('aname'))
        return cleaned_data
```

Now, I have to define `MyWidget` to allow me to display a list of `<input type="hidden">`, but I would like to know if this solution sound acceptable. Maybe I could have done this in `clean_aname()` too.

Answer (score 0):

You could try implementing this using a set of forms (called formsets within Django), in which each form would be an instance of the validation form you want. For instance,

```
class ValidationForm(forms.Form):
    aname = forms.CharField()

    def clean_aname(self):
        aname = self.cleaned_data['aname']
        # TODO validate aname
        return aname

    def save(self, commit=False):
        # TODO implement this form's save logic
        return 'It works!'
```

For creating a set of those forms (see [formset documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/)), do:

```
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory
ValidationFormSet = formset_factory(ValidationForm)
```

On your view, use the ValidationFormSet for receiving the data:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ValidationFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            # All anames were validated by clean_aname
            results = form.save()

            for r in results:
                print r # Should print 'It works!'
    else:
        form = ValidationFormSet()

    return <your_result>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that it's to extend a ModelForm. Please see my edit and advise if I'm going on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass multiple forms to your view using prefix, like this:

```
jsondumplist = ['jsondump1', 'jsondump2', 'jsondump3', 'jsondump4'....]
if request.method == 'POST':
        forms = [YourForm(request.POST, prefix=x) for x in jsondumplist]                        
        for f in forms:
                if f.is_valid():
                        f.save()                 
else:
        forms = [YourForm(prefix=x) for x in jsondumplist]
```

YourForm could have just the single field you are interested in, or several.

```
class YourForm(forms.Form):
    aname = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

Then, your template will look something like this:

```
{% for form in forms %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: As said previously, I have no idea what the `jsondumplist` is like. It's dynamically generated on the client-side. Please see my edit if you have any comments.